# ASP CheckBox1_CheckedChanged event not working.

Tags: asp.net, html, user-controls, checkbox

I just want to Visible a Html Table(id='xx') when user clicked on check-box in ASP page. And once the user untick on the check-box The Table should invisible again.

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td colspan='2'>
               <table id='xx'>
                      <tr>
                          <td colspan='2'>
                                Student Information :
                           </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                           <td>
                             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Student name :"></asp:Label>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200px">
                                   </asp:DropDownList>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
    ...
```

I have tried this code:

```
   protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            // need a way to hide the Table id='xx' 
        }
        else {
            DropDownList1.Visible = true; // This is also not working
        }
    }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here...

> 1. Make the Table server control using runat = "server"
> 2. On Check/UnCheck the CheckBox control, set the display attribute to True/False.

### Option 1  Handle at Server side

```
<table id='xx' runat = "server">
```

Now you can access the table control like below

```
xx.Visible  = true/false;
```

---

### Option 2  Handle at Client Side

```
<asp:CheckBox onclick="return SelectChk(this);" ID="chk" ></asp:CheckBox>
```

**JavaScript Function**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SelectChk(CtlId) {
        var IsChecked = document.getElementById(CtlId.id).checked;
        if (IsChecked) {
            document.getElementById(<%=xx.ClientID%>).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById(<%=xx.ClientID%>).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **AutoPostBack="true"** for CheckBox control while postback.

Comment: Deepu: Thank you for your help. I forget to do that.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox1" Text="check" Checked="true" AutoPostBack="true"
                OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
            <table id='xx' runat="server">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        Student Information :
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Student name :"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.xx.Visible = CheckBox1.Checked;
}
```